# django time zone aware setup return local datetime in query

Tags: python, django, timezone

I have a django 1.5 setup with

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Jerusalem'
USE_TZ = True
```

in my settings file. I always set my datetime fields with tz aware datetime.

however when querying an object with models.DateTimeField

```
root.alert_set.all()
```

I get a local datetime instead of a tz aware one.

any ideas?

Thanks,
Shy

Comment: Do you get any errors/warnings when this query is run?

Comment: how do you set the timezone? with `datetime.now()`? or `with timezone.now()`?

Comment: do you use datetime
or you are using django.utils import timezone ?

Comment: d[field.name] = make_aware(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(field_data), cluster_tz)  cls.objects.create(**d)